# Outlook Add-in - Dynamic Control Button Highlight On Click

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed an add-in built with yo generator (Node.js) that works as a configurator which enables the outlook compose to enable/disable sending a copy of the new email to a custom url on-send.

There's a control button added that says 'Toggle Send to cCRM' but I would prefer a toggle text dynamically from 'Enable send to cCRM' to 'Disable send to cCRM' and vice-versa when clicking the control button to improve UI experience. Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: By "control button" do you mean a button in a task pane or a custom ribbon button? If you mean a custom ribbon button, then Eugene is correct. The button label is set in the add-in manifest and it cannot be dynamically changed.  (If this was Excel, you could have 2 buttons and the handler for each enables the other and disables itself, but that is not yet supported in Outlook.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Toggle buttons as well as callbacks are not supported in web add-ins. See [Control types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#control-types) for more information.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Are COM add-ins considerable for this type of implementation or not? Anyways, thank you for clearing it up.

Comment: Yes, you can easily implement the required functionality in VSTO/COM add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature to dynamically change the icon in the ribbon, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.