# Outlook "Command Add-in" Button Border

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed an Outlook Add-in with a Taskpane and a Command Add-in, using the Yo Office Tool with a Web Add-in and Javascript as Code base. So far everything works like we wanted it except for the Command Add-in where we would like to visually tell the user the actual state of the command. Like with either a changed Icon and Text combination (aka a Toggle Button like the Outlook Dark Mode Add-in) or a Border around the Add-in Command Button. Just like it, right now, works for embedded outlook Add-ins and COM Add-ins too. See this screenshot: [image: Outlook Add-ins with Toggle function or Button Border]

I am searching the Web for days now for an answer or a hint. Also, I have gone through the Add-in samples but could not find something which would lead me into the right direction. I've read on a post here [Outlook Add-in - Dynamic Control Button Highlight On Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71329066/outlook-add-in-dynamic-control-button-highlight-on-click) that for Web Add-ins this function is not implemented yet, same as Callback functionality. But my Web based Add-in do have and use Callbacks, and they work. So my Question is: Is there a way how I can use Button Toggle or Button Border with a Web Add-in, or does this only work with COM Add-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

The example is enabling or disabling a control, but I think you should be able to adjust other properties (like text and icon) as well.

**Update:**
I found out from someone more knowledgeable than me about Outlook that the feature I linked is for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint and has not been ported to Outlook yet.  We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request” 
https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Comment: I'm afraid not. Nothing else about the appearance of the button can be changed at runtime.

Comment: No, I haven't seen this page. Thank you very much! That should exactly do the job. Well, theoretically I just define two buttons (Actions) which will have their own icon and text and then I switch the activation state of them, depending on the user action.

Comment: This is one step back. But at least I have now clarification and can concentrate on more imported parts. I already posted a feature request, regarding the enabling and disabling of the Outlook Web Add-in Commands, but since someone requested that feature already in April 2021, my hopes are not high that this will happen in the near feature. Looks like that, I'll probably port it to an COM Add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Chaning the visual appearance of the button for an Add-in Command is not possible with Office Web Add-ins, except for the case that @DarrenMiller mentioned: enabling and disabling.